# run a deep linking to open application using java

Tags: java, javafx, deep-linking

I want to open an app with a deep linking like

steam://connect/62.210.142.56:27155

if using browser it open steam application but using httpurlconnection return a MalformedURLException and using a javafx webview nothing happend

I only want to open steam app programmaticaly in desktop

Comment: You need to add protocol handler for the `stream` protocol...

Comment: can you explain more and it is "steam" not "stream"

Comment: Just read thru https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it maybe some one use it.

if you use java.awt.Desktop you can run default browser of system like this
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://example.com"));

but if you set a deep linking uri it open application without open browser like this
Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("steam://connect/62.210.142.56:27155"));